# Objective C- Confusing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using [NSString initwithdata]

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, exc-bad-access

I am having some trouble using the data that I receive from a remote server. This is how I take in the data from my nsinputstream:

```
 case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        if(!_data)
        {
            _data = [NSMutableData data];
        }

        uint8_t buffer = malloc(1024);
        NSInteger *len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
        if(len)
        {
            _data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:1024];
            [self closeThread];
        }
        shouldClose = YES;

        break;
    }
```

In the same class I have this function to return the data in order to use it in different classes:

```
 -(NSData *)returnData {
      return self.data;
  }
```

In the view controller that I want to use the data in I have this code to retrieve the data for use:

```
 _schools = [_server returnData];
 NSString *schoolString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.schools encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//exc_bad_access
```

From what I understand about EXC_BAD_ACCESS exceptions they usually mean that you are trying to access data that either doesn't exist or is not allocated. The _schools variable shows a size of 1024 bytes so I know there is memory correctly allocated for it. Is there something else going wrong that I am missing?

Comment: Why are you using `_schools` in some places but `self.schools` in other places (very next line)?

Comment: Same error if you replace `self.schools` with `_schools`?

Comment: Why don't you just do `NSString *schoolString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[_server returnData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` Does that produce the same error?

Comment: I tried self.schools because I was reading up on the problem and some people said that might be the solution. @nhgrif, I will try your suggestion

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any real difference between `self.schools` or `_schools`.  I only commented on it because you should be consistent (I never synthesize and always use `self.` syntax for clarity).

Comment: @nhgrif, this did not solve the problem, I get the same error

Comment: Are you getting any sort of a stacktrace in the slightest?  Usually `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` will be accompanied by a stacktrace referencing a specific call somewhere.  How is `_server` declared?

Comment: _server is declared in my viewDidLoad as simply _server = [[Server alloc] init]; The exc_bad_access exception points to a line of assembly that contains the mov command

Comment: Is the `NSString *schoolString = ...` line also in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: "schools" returning a length value has nothing to do with whether the data buffer is there or not.

Comment: No, the line of code is in a function to update the UI after receiving the data

Comment: Do `NSLog(@"schools ptr = %p", [_schools bytes]);`

Comment: And if that works do `NSLog(@"schools first byte = %c", *[_schools bytes]);`

Comment: Ah yes, that displays a ptr of 0x0, which I'm assuming means the data was never retrieved from the buffer

Comment: It means that there is no buffer.  Hard to say where it got lost -- you need to check all along the way, from the malloc forward.  (Remember that malloc can return null.)

Comment: Wait, malloc() returns a block of memory proportional to the size requested in the form of a pointer.  Why exactly are you trying to fit it into a plain `uint8_t`?  Also, CLANG should be warning you to take the address of that buffer so you can pass the correct type to `-[NSInputStream read:maxLength:]`, which should have been your first indication that you'd done something wrong.  There is no buffer past the first 8 bits of this thing, hence the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have mixed up the types of the variables on these two lines:

```
uint8_t buffer = malloc(1024);
NSInteger *len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
```

In its current form, you will `malloc`'ate 1024 bytes of memory, and attempt to store the pointer to said memory in a `uint8_t` (which CLANG will rightly scream at you for), thus truncating the pointer and not providing a buffer, but rather a single unsigned 8-bit byte for the stream to attempt to read into.  Also, `-[NSInputStream read:maxLength:]` does not return `NSInteger *`, just plain `NSInteger`, so all you need to do is swap the pointers on the two variables:

```
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(1024);
NSInteger len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the missing `*`.  Figured there was something flaky in there but couldn't figure what.  (It helps to actually pay attention to the warning messages sometimes.)